# Validate password match laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate if the user has matching passwords but I'm stuck with this error when the user submit Unmatched passwords `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`  But if the passwords matches then it works fine, how can I solve this?

Controller

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request, $token)
{

 $this->validate($request, [
     'password' => ['required','confirmed'],
]);

 $password = $request->password;
 $tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')
 ->where('token', $token)->first();

 $user = User::where('email', $tokenData->email)->first();
 if ( !$user ) return redirect()->to('home');

 $user->password = Hash::make($password);
 $user->update();


 Auth::login($user);


DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $user->email)->delete();


return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

Blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update',$token) }}">
@csrf

<div class="control">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required>
</div>


 <div class="control">
        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" required>
</div>


<button type="submit">
    {{ __('Submit') }}
</button>
```

Route

```
Route::post('reset-password/{token}', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@resetPassword')->name('password.update');
```

Comment: Failed validation redirects to previous URL but whatever that URL is, it has a POST method signature while the redirect is a GET

Comment: @user11710915 that is the problem. If you want to show a view, it should be a GET method (because you get a resource). Now, your GET route has a form that makes a POST request, when the login fail, Laravel executes a GET request to the previous route. in your case this previous route seems to be a POST route instead of a GET one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
<input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" required>
```

With this:

```
<input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password_confirmation" required>
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-confirmed

And also make sure that you have closing `form` tag at the bottom `</form>` is missing from your view as you've shared.

Make sure you run `php artisan route:list` to make sure that your route is the only one existing with that endpoint and the method type is `POST` for sure as well.